# How do I add a navigation item to a Table View Controller (with static cells) in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, interface-builder, navigationbar

I’m building my first iOS app using Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1.

My app is basically a View Controller which contains a Table View and is embedded in a Navigation Controller. When I tap a cell in the Table View the app transitions to a subordinate View Controller. Because I’m using a Naviagtion Controller the subordinate view already has a navigation bar at the top with a helpful button back to its parent.

I also want to reveal a Settings screen when the user taps a “Settings” button in the navigation bar. Using a new View Controller as a placeholder for the Settings screen works – I can reveal the Settings screen with a Modal segue and the screen can have a button or navigation item to unwind the segue back to my initial view.

Everything works and it’s all good.

However I want to build my Settings screen using a Table View with static cells. I just need a couple of cell groups with various controls where the user can set their preferences. For Xcode to support static cells I have to use a Table View Controller as the basis for my Settings screen. This is where the problems arise.

**With a Table View Controller I can no longer place a button or navigation item on the screen to trigger the unwind segue.**

I could make the segue a “Show” so it becomes part of the navigation hierarchy imposed by the Navigation Controller. This does provide a navigation bar on my Settings screen with a navigation item that transitions back to the original View Controller.

But this isn’t what I want. From a UX point of view the Settings page is now a subordinate page in the hierarchy. What I really want is for the Settings page to be revealed modally with a horizontal flip so it feels like a separate screen in the app.

So my question is, how can I add the necessary UI widgets to a Table View Controller so that I can trigger the unwind segue? Or am I overlooking something more fundamental in my application’s architecture? To me this seems like a fairly obvious approach to including a settings screen but after hours of searching I can’t find instances of anyone else having this problem. Nor can I find any tutorials or examples of how to implement an in-app settings screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your problem correctly. I think you want to add some buttons to UITableViewController. For this here is my solution. Embedding UITableViewController in UINavigationController will work for you. When tapped on Settings button present navigation controller modally. As navigation controller have table view controller as root view controller, tableviewcontroller will have navigation bar. You can add your buttons to it.

Comment: Thanks for that – it works! I had understood Navigation Controllers as parent items in a hierarchy, rather as facilitating navigation in other ways.